# Apply Change of Variables so that $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(t)F_N(x-t)dt=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x-t)F_N(t)dt$ (Should be easy and quick)

Tags: calculus

Just need someone to remind me again how to do a proper change of variables, consider $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(t)F_N(x-t)dt=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x-t)F_N(t)dt$

Let $u=x-t\Rightarrow t=x-u\Rightarrow du=-dt\Rightarrow f(t)=f(x-u)$ and $F_N(x-t)=F_N(u)$. Also, $-\pi=x-u\Rightarrow u=x+\pi$ and $\pi=x-u\Rightarrow u=x-\pi$. However, $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(t)F_N(x-t)dt=-\int_{x+\pi}^{x-\pi}f(x-u)F_N(u)du=\int_{x-\pi}^{x+\pi}f(x-u)F_N(u)du$. Considering dummy variables, how is my logic not producing $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x-t)F_N(t)dt$

Comment: Your change of variables is correct, possibly $fF_N$ have some property which allows to shift integral by $x$.

Comment: Could I consider having parameter $x$ taking on a particular value that would enclose it onto the boundary that we need? I'm given $f$ is continuous only on $[-\pi,\pi]$

Comment: $f$ and $F$ must be $2\pi$-periodic.
If $u$ is $2\pi$-periodic then :
$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} u = \int_{x-\pi}^{x+\pi} u$$
for any $x$

Comment: Yes that helped explain this